# Compute Sha256 array using JDK libs

Tags: java

I have some code that computes a hash of a byte array using Guava's `Hashing` class

```
private String getShaForFile(byte[] bytes) {
    return Hashing.sha256().hashBytes(bytes).toString();
}
```

However, a linting tool is complaining that this class is unstable, so I'd like to replace this implementation with one that uses the JDK classes (I'd rather not add a dependency like Bouncy Castle just for the sake of this one method).

Comment: Please add the warning/error you get regards the unstable class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass algorithm to `MessageDigest.instance`

```
 MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
```

Code would be something around the lines as below:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = md.digest(
  originalString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String sha256 = new String(Hex.encode(hash));
```

You can also use **Apache common's** API

```
String sha256hex = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(originalString);
```